# Input text doesn't looks like other Bootstrap controls when works with angular 2 and ng2-completer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to use ng2-completer with angular2.
Added the imports

```
import {
    NgModule,
    Component
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Ng2CompleterModule } from "ng2-completer";
```

Then wrote the code:

```
<ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="captain" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [datasource]="captains" [minSearchLength]="0" class="form-control"></ng2-completer>
```

But it doesn't looks like other bootstrap controls.
This is my package.json if relevant:

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -f ./*.js; rm -f ./*.js.map; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js.map",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "serve": "live-server --host=localhost --port=8080 .",
    "go": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run serve\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "express": "4.15.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sass-breakpoints": "^2.1.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "tslint": "3.7.0-dev.2",
    "typescript": "1.9.0-dev.20160409",
    "typings": "0.8.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "1.0.0",
    "live-server": "0.9.0",
    "typescript": "1.7.3",
    "grunt": "0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "description": "test project for real estate with using angular 2 and node.js",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "author": "Tuvia Khusid"
}
```

Does anyone have idea, why it works but doesn't looks like other controls?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Does your NgModule include the option bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]

Comment: No. Do I have to add it? Do you have an example, please?

Comment: `ng2-completer` [demo](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/tree/master/demo) uses bootstrap. you can check the code to see how it's done there

Comment: Thanks mate, I have copied my code from there. Maybe missed something :)